# How would I detect touch screens in jquery and hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, detection

How would I use this code:

```
function is_touch_device() {
  return !!('ontouchstart' in window) // works on most browsers 
      || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window); // works on ie10
};
```

to detect touch screens and hide a set of divs with the same class.

Comment: `if (is_touch_device()) $('.myclass').hide();` ?

Comment: Do I miss something in your question ?

Comment: I think that will work I will try. I am still getting to grips with jquery and I know I should learn more before trying something this ambitious but I learn better by doing then seeing it in action.

Comment: Thank you @dystroy that works a treat. I will accept the answer by Micheal which is the same as yours. thanks you were first though.

Comment: WARNING: I've been bitten by `onmsgesturechange`, it's available on IE10 even if the device is NOT a touch device, it can't be trusted to reliably determine if a device is touch or not!

Comment: Hi Rob. it still has the desired result on the desktop version. I will check it on a surface and come back on here.

Comment: just check `'ontouchend' in document`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would simply call the function and use basic logic.

```
if (is_touch_device()) {
  $('.yourclass').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be implemented like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  if (is_touch_device()){
    var divs=document.getElementsByClassName( 'yourclassname');
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
      divs[i].style.display='none'; 
  }
}

function is_touch_device() {
  return !!('ontouchstart' in window) // works on most browsers 
      || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window); // works on ie10
};
```

Comment: As jQuery is available, I don't think it really makes sense to take the long way.

Comment: Assuming you're not using jQuery.

Comment: thanks @ncksllvn for showing an alternative to using jquery. I need to lend more time to completely learning this language.