# How do I make my site detect if a mouse is being used, then add a class to an element if it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I basically have some buttons on my homepage that are blurred/out of focus, then come into focus when hovered over - but, of course, there's no way to appreciate this effect in a touch-only browser. Is there a way to only add that blurred effect if the page detects that the user  has a mouse?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857320/how-would-i-detect-touch-screens-in-jquery-and-hide-a-div

Comment: also have to consider devices with both

Comment: This sounds like [mystery meat navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation).  Seriously, don't do this.  See also:  http://www.stucox.com/blog/the-good-and-bad-of-level-4-media-queries/ and http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be with css hacks and you have to check whether the device is mobile and if it is then the button would be put it focus. Here is what the css would look like:

```
@media only screen {
    .button {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```